# Optional column value in SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, sqldatasource

I have this `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleXexdb %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleXexdb.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="select col1, col2, col3 from table where col1 < 2000 and (col2 = :col2 OR :col2 is null)"
     OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"
    >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="codagent" Name="col2" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue=""/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

`codagent` is an `<asp:TextBox>` and the user can put a value or nothing (""), if the user leaves the TextBox with nothing, the `SqlDataSource` retrieves no values. My goal is allow user to get all the col2 values, without filter

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you really want only the ones where col1 is less than 2000, or if they enter null into the text box to get all of the ones including where col1 was >= 2000? And have you tried not using an empty string to null and using col2 = '' ?

Comment: @RobG I want all the values of col2 and only the ones where col1 is less than 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleXexdb %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleXexdb.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="select col1, col2, col3 from table where col1 < 2000 and (col2 = :col2 OR (:col2 is null))"
    >

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="codagent" Name="col2" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" DefaultValue=""/>
    </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your SQL to something like this

```
SelectCommand="select col1, col2, col3 from table where col1 < 2000 and (col2 = :col2 OR  (:col2 is null AND 1=1)"
```

I'm not really sure if such expressions are possible in Oracle since I don't have any experience with it but this is the logic that is used to accomplish the same thing in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using the **[`OnSelecting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting.aspx)** event of `SqlDataSource`, use this event to modify your `Select` command.

Also, since you want the user to retrieve all `col2` values, in actuality, all such columns with `col1<2000` will only be retrieved.
[ Means, there can be `col2` values corresponding to which col1> 2000, so such `col2` will not be displayed at all ]

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, 
SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(codagent.Text))
    {
      e.Command="select col1, col2, col3 from table where col1 < 2000";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use subquery. following code is giving col2, col3 whether col1 is empty or not.

```
select (select col1 from table1 where col1 ='') as col1, col2, col3 from table1
```